# How to redirect to home.php after facebook oAuth login?

Tags: php, facebook

I tried to put  header( 'Location: home.php' ) ; into the function login with facebook but after I successfully login, the page still doesn't redirect to homepage.

Anyone can help me out? Thanks!

```
function login(response, info){
            if (response.authResponse) {

               var accessToken =   response.authResponse.accessToken;

                userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + info.id + '/picture">' + info.name
                                                                 + "<br /> Your Access Token: " + accessToken;
                button.innerHTML                               = 'Logout';
                showLoader(false);
                document.getElementById('other').style.display = "block";
                header( 'Location: home.php' ) ;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up your PHP and JavaScript. [Header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is a PHP function. You can't use it with JavaScript.

You might want to try a JavaScript redirect method -

```
var homeUrl = 'home.php';
top.location.href = homeUrl;
```